# How to build multiple apps in angular 7 project in a single build command?

Tags: angular, build, angular7

Now i need to specify each application name individually in "ng build" to build each app in angular 7 project (eg. ng build Myfirstapp, ng build MySecondApp).

I need to build all apps in a single build command (using "ng build" only builded the app name specified in "defaultProject" in angular.json).

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a script in your `package.json` file that runs all ng builds, e.g.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build Myfirstapp && ng build MySecondApp"
}
```

Then simply run

```
npm run build
```